# How to use OSX 10.14 SDK on Xcode 11?

Tags: xcode, macos-catalina, qtkit

I have a project being developed on Xcode 10.2.1 which uses the (32-bit) QTKit framework, specifically QTMovieModernizer.  The project deploys on OSX 10.14.6.

On Xcode 11, this fails (which is somewhat expected):

```
#import <QTKit/QTMovieModernizer.h>
```

**How to I get Xcode 11.x to eschew the MacOSX 10.15 SDK and use the 10.14 SDK instead?**

Previously, subbing in SDK's was an easier task, but I don't see the option any longer. I guess I'm okay with continuing with Xcode 10.x for now.

Answer (score 3):

Just symlinking the 10.15 SDK as 10.14 didn't work for me (since there are, of course, some differences between the two).

I had to [download the 10.14 SDK](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases) from a third-party archive and manually unzip it to:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in similar situation (YMMV):

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
sudo ln -s MacOSX.sdk/ MacOSX10.14.sdk
```